# Can the Stream returned by JdbcTemplate.queryForStream() be parallelized?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Just to give some context, I am using JDBC Template (and MySQL JDBC driver) to access data stored in MySQL. It's a Spring Boot application. I want to do filtering, sorting and pagination on the application side. So, I am streaming the data using `JdbcTemplate.queryForStream` method.

In order to process really large dataset (forget about sorting for a moment, that's a different problem to tackle) can I parallelize the Stream? Does the underlying datasource and JDBC connection support that? If not, is there a way?

I want to do something like this:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
List<String> myData = jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(mySelectQuery)
                                  .parallel()  // Check this out! Is this okay?
                                  .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 18)
                                  .skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
                                  .limit(pageSize)
                                  .map(Person::getName)
                                  .toList();
```

Comment: All your operations in your example should ideally be done on a query level, especially the paging! Also, don’t forget to close the Stream when using Streams. Otherwise you never free up the connection

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not support parallel in this moment.
By referring [JdbcTemplate.queryForStream](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v6.0.9/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L479)

```java
    @Override
    public <T> Stream<T> queryForStream(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException {
        class StreamStatementCallback implements StatementCallback<Stream<T>>, SqlProvider {
            @Override
            public Stream<T> doInStatement(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                Connection con = stmt.getConnection();
                return new ResultSetSpliterator<>(rs, rowMapper).stream().onClose(() -> {
                    JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
                    JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
                    DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
                });
            }
            @Override
            public String getSql() {
                return sql;
            }
        }

        return result(execute(new StreamStatementCallback(), false));
    }
```

and we can see stream is implemented through [ResultSetSpliterator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v6.0.9/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L1699), checking the stream method,

```
        public Stream<T> stream() {
            return StreamSupport.stream(this, false);
        }
```

The second parameter `false` of [StreamSupport.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream(java.util.Spliterator,boolean)) indicate that the stream is not parallel.

Based on given example, filter, skip, limit should be done in database side,
like using WHERE, LIMIT clause in SQL.